# Expected value for a combination of density functions

Tags: statistics, random-variables, expected-value, density-function

Let $f_1,...,f_k$ density functions with continuous random variables $X_1,...,X_k$ and define

$$g(x):=\dfrac{f_1(x)+...+f_k(x)}{k}.\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$$

If $E[X_j]=j$, for $j=1,...,k$ and Y is a random variable with density $g$. Find $E[Y]$

Is it ok to do

$$E[Y]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}yg(y)dy=\dfrac{1}{k}
(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x_1f_1(x_1)dx_1+...+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x_kf_k(x_k)dx_k)$$

$$=\dfrac{1}{k}(E[X_1]+...+E[X_k])=\dfrac{1}{k}(1+...+k)=\dfrac{k(k+1)}{2k}$$??

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is fine. My working below doesn't change the integration variable to $x_i$.

\begin{align}
E[Y] &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty yg(y) \, dy \\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty y\cdot \frac1k\sum_{i=1}^k f_k(y) \, dy \\
&=\frac1k \int_{-\infty}^\infty yf_k(y) \, dy\\
&=\frac1k \sum_{i=1}^k E[X_k]\\
&= \frac{k(k+1)}{2k}\\
&=\frac{k+1}2
\end{align}